How do I delete all rows that have non-integer values in a panda dataframe?
I need to clean up a data frame, in which I have to delete all rows that have non-integer values. There's only one columns that have this issue.
My code right now:
data=pd.read_csv('house_data_2024.csv')
data.head()  

id    price  bedrooms  bathrooms  sqm_living     sqm_lot  waterfront
0          1   221900         3       1.00  109.624675  524.897807           0
1          2   538000         3       2.25  238.758826  672.798216           0
2          3   180000         2       1.00   71.534745  929.022668           0
3          4   604000         4       3.00  182.088443  464.511334           0
4          5   510000         3       2.00  156.075808  750.650316           0
...      ...      ...       ...        ...         ...         ...         ...
21596  21596   520000         2       2.25  142.140468   91.137124           0
21597  21597   679950         5       2.75  334.448160  876.718692           0
21598  21598  1575000         4       3.25  316.796730  940.635452           0
21599  21599   541800         4       2.50  289.669268  730.769231           0
21600  21600   810000         4       3.00  370.680045  728.167967           0 

bathrooms is the column with this issue.
I tried to extract the value then use for loop to drop each row but it doesn't work.

without knowing the type of dadta is difficult but this can help df[pd.to_numeric(df['bathrooms'], errors='coerce').notna() & pd.to_numeric(df['bathrooms'], errors='coerce').apply(float.is_integer)]

All your rows seem to have non-integer values (floats). Do you mean non- numeric? It would be better if you gave examples of the rows to remove.
